# Populate an object and post it through jquery ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsp

In my jsp page i have some input tags with id of 'opt'. I need to get the value of all of them and create the following list:

```
Votes= {
vote={opt:'one'}, vote={opt:'two'}, vote={opt:'three'},...
}
```

How can i do it? 
I have written the following code to get the value those inputs and store them in an array but it only gets the first of them:

```
Var opts=[] , ids;
$("#myform").each(function(){
ids=$("#opt").val();
opts.push(ids);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here try this

```
...
var votes = new Array(); // the array to hold the votes
document.querySelectorAll("#opt").forEach(function (elem) {
    votes.push(elem.value);
});

$.ajax({
...
"data": votes,
...
});
```

I hope this helps

Comment: Tnx.Actually instead of options it would be votes. now i can get those ids. But how can i create that list? Each element within votes should be of type vote with a property of opt. Ajax still doesn't work cos votes is not in correct format. It is just an array of strings not a list of vote objects

Comment: Yeh.. that is me (:

Answer (score 0):

In order to send through ajax without problem it is enough to modify line 3 of the answer as below:

```
Votes.push({'Opt':elem.value});
```

Now votes will be a list of vote objects and not just an array of strings. Therefore ajax will work properly